# How to set up Jenkins with Nginx and a Node.js application

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, jenkins, digital-ocean

### What I want

Hi, my problem is the following: I want to access Jenkins which I have running on my server through my browser at `https://my-domain.com/jenkins`.

### What I have

I have DO droplet with **Ubuntu 16.04 which runs Nginx** which works as a proxy server, forwarding all the traffic towards my **Node.js application through https**, which works fine when I visit my site at `https://my-domain.com`.

I have successfully installed and run Jenkins (if I run a `systemctl status jenkins` I can see that it's active), however I can't figure out, how my Nginx should be configured to access Jenkins properly.

What I tried to do is to set up a new location for it, but the result is that if I visit `https://my-domain.com/jenkins` it redirects to `https://my-domain.com/login?from=%2Fjenkins` and serves my Node.js application.

### Nginx config (`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`)

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name my-domain.com;

    # Access and error log for Jenkins
    access_log /var/log/nginx/jenkins.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/jenkins.error.log;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain.com/privkey.pem;

# Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # Settings for Jenkins
    # include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    # proxy_read_timeout 90s;
    # proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080 https://my-domain.com;
}


location /jenkins {
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_read_timeout 90s;
}
}
```

Maybe the actual issue is not with the Nginx configuration but with Jenkins? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out. I realized that instead of `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;` I had to use `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/jenkins/;`, and redirect to https with `proxy_redirect http:// https://;`

For further help please visit: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+behind+an+NGinX+reverse+proxy